# KnockoutJS passing ko.computed values to a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have a working knockout js script, myValues is an array result of a ko.computed, then I pass it down to myValues2 which calls a myFunction to make each object in that array as "observable". This works but I wanted to call myFunction in self.myValues so that I wouldn't have to create another observableArray myValues2. Can you help me combine the script of myValues and myValues2 so that I can finally delete self.myValues2. Here is my code:

```
var myFunction = function (id, name, amount, automatic) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.Amount = ko.observable(amount);
    self.Automatic = ko.observable(automatic);
};

self.myValues = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.completeList(), function (ded) {
        return ded.automatic() == true;
    });
});

self.myValues2 = ko.observableArray();
self.myValues2(ko.utils.arrayMap(self.myValues(), function (dd) {
    return new myFunction(dd.id(), dd.name(), dd.amount(), dd.automatic());
}));
```

Comment: there is no need of using `arrayMap` here as you are trying to pass observable's only i.e `dd.id()` i.e you can use `myValues` in view

Answer (score 0):

```
self.completeList()
```

how defined this array?

Because you began to filter this list by automatic field and then to fill other list. Strange order.

```
return ded.automatic() == true;
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/beylkhanovdamir/dpxgcjfs/8/
Change this jsfiddle sample to show your problem.